# pass div class value to a variable in php

Tags: php, variables

Here i want to pass div class value to the variable so far i had done like this.
Here is my div `<div class="modal_content_payment"></div>` and here i have value getting `20` now i want to store that value in to a variable and use it in a PHP function.

my PHP code looks like this...

```
 <?php $p_amount=$this->db->get_where('tbl_abc',array('abc_id'=>`here i want that value`))->row();?>
```

i got value in div by using jquery see my code

```
<script>
function modal_payment(id,title)
{
  var measurement_id=id;
  $("#measmnt_id").val(measurement_id);
  var url='<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/view_particular_amount_modal';

  $.post(url,{measurement_id:measurement_id}, function(result)
  {

     $(".modal_content_payment").html(result);
    jQuery('#modal_payment').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static',keyboard :false});

  });      
 }

</script>
```

first i want to store that div value in to a variable so i can use it in PHP please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data through JavaScript.

```
Function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

}

Or you can use AJAX functionality.

Comment: see i got div value by using Jquery only

Comment: yes of-course.., but in your question you are asking to get value in php

Comment: you can get value from jQuery

Comment: see i got value in div by using jquery now i want to place that value in to a variable

Comment: Please create a new question for that. And mansion question clearly.